# Word that means "healing" or "spiritually healing"?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, synonyms

I know there is a word that means 'healing' as in "The therapy session was very ______", blank meaning it was healing (possibly of emotional wounds from the past).

Comment: I think you mean "spiritually healing" (as in healing to the spirit) rather than "Spiritual Healing" (healing by the spirit)!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I often see "[cathartic](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/catharsis)" in this context, which describes the release of negative emotions.  I think this word implies a healing process.

Comment: That's the word, Cathartic. Couldnt for the life of me find it in the thesaurus. Thanks

Comment: Today, the word is used more in the metaphorical than the absolute sense. So  much so most are aware only of such use and not the dictionary meaning.

Answer (score 5):

I think the word you want is

Therapeutic

Comment: Which actually comes from the Greek θεραπεύω, meaning *to heal*.

Comment: Makes me think "have one of the doctor's [wholesome](http://thesaurus.com/browse/wholesome) salubrious therapeutic  restoratives!" ... though I doubt that's exactly the connotation the OP intended.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest **sanative** or **sanatory**. These words mean 'healing' and could be used in your sentence to convey this meaning.

> The therapy session was very sanative.

I think both of the suggested words have some problems.

1. *Cathartic* could mean either *a release of strong emotions* or *purgative* or *laxative*, so in your context there is a danger of the word being misconstrued.
2. *Therapeutic* suits better, but does not fit well in your sentence. Saying "The therapy session was therapeutic" sounds repetitious.